# Get name of specific Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, reflection

Is this the best method for getting the name of a specific Exception in C#:

```
ex.GetType().ToString()
```

It is in a generic exception handler:

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ex.GetType().Name` or `ex.GetType().FullName` for the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 16):

Try `ex.GetType().Name`

```
try
{           
    object test = null;
    test.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name);
}
```

Gives this..

```
NullReferenceException
```